# What does it mean that a new substitution jutsu is available?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2

I've recently picked up [Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Shippuden:_Ultimate_Ninja_Storm_2) (guilty pleasure) and find some of the text prompts the game throws at me rather baffling.

Recently, after performing rather well at a specific fight during the "Ultimate Adventure" mode, I received a message that a "new substitution jutsu" is available.

To my best knowledge, "substitution jutsu" in the game's context refers to the action you perform when blocking just before an attack lands, avoiding all damage. I only know of one way to perform these using exactly one button on the controller and the move always looks the same.

What is this "new substitution jutsu" and how do I access/use it? Is it only relevant in another game mode? Did I misinterpret something the game was trying to tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start a match you have the option to select the form that your substitution jutsu takes. All of the characters have their own primary form, but you can (for the most part) switch between different peoples types.

When you are on the character selection screen look near your character, there will be a picture of a log. If you push the button listed next (or on that picture) you can select the style of substitution jutsu you'd like to use.

( I think it's L1 but I don't have the game on me at the moment to load up)

Comment: *For the most part: Some character specific substitutions (Like Tobi's reality warping) don't seem unlockable for all characters.